# How to test blocking handlers with EmbeddedChannel

Tags: testing, netty

I want to test some handlers with the help of EmbeddedChannel.

One of the handlers is blocking and in the context of the pipeline I'm using the method addLast(EventExecutorGroup group, ChannelHandler... handlers) to add it to the pipeline. Like this:

```
pipeline.addLast( new NonBlockingHandler1(), new NonBlockingHandler2());
pipeline.addLast( eventGroup, new BlockingHandler())
```

The only way to add handlers to the EmbeddedChannel is via the constructor. But here I can't specify any EventExecutorGroup to be used for the one blocking handler. How can I test now the blocking handler?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `channel.pipeline().addLast(...)`

Comment: I would like to add a blocking handler to the pipeline, and addLast(...) (with one argument) is only to be used for non blocking handlers.